# How to get work Infinite scroll depending on div container's scroll position?

Tags: infinite-scroll

I'm looking for a infinite scroll script, but can't find one which really fits my needs. I have found one which would be great, but the problem is that the script works after the User scrolls down using the browser SCROLLBAR. Instead it should load and display more data depending on the div "scroll" position.

How can i do that? It doesn't have to be this script but it should include a mysql query function so I can implement mine easily, because I'm really a newbie in Javascript, jQuery etc. A tutorial would do it also...but can't really find one. All of them are depending on the browser's scroll position.

That's the script I'm using:
[github.com/moemoe89/infinite-scroll/blob/master/index.php](https://github.com/moemoe89/infinite-scroll/blob/master/index.php)

I made only one modification:

```
news_area{ width:400px; height:95px;  overflow:auto;}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please add the relevant parts of the code to the question, so the question can stand on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$(window).scrollTop()` use any container that you would want to get it's scrolling position from, like `$('.scrollable').scrollTop()`.

```js
$('.scrollable').on('scroll', function(){
  var $el = $(this);
  $('.scrolled').text($(this).scrollTop());
  if( $el.innerHeight()+$el.scrollTop() >= this.scrollHeight-5 ){
    var d = new Date();
    $el.append('more text added on '+d.getHours()+':'+d.getMinutes()+':'+d.getSeconds()+'<br>');
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Scrolled from top: <span class="scrolled">0</span></p>
<div class="scrollable">
  text<br>
  text<br>
  text<br>
  text<br>
  text<br>
  text<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! :))
I tried it like this but it doesn't work:


$('#news_area').on('scroll', function(){$('.scrolled').text($(this).scrollTop());});
 
  if($('#news_area').scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {}

Comment: I have updated example to show an actual infinite scroll in a div and how you can add your own content.

Comment: Ahhh, you're a genius! Thank you so much. It works like charm. :)))

Comment: May I ask you something else? Is there a way to simple display the content like the facebook private messenger and display more content by scrolling upwards instead of down?

Comment: Perhaps you might want to ask another question at stackoverflow. Make sure to make it as specific as possible, so others can help you.