# Infinitely scrolling <div>

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

## problem

How do I make a `<div>` tag scroll infinitely like it does in many SVG editors like Figma, Gravit, etc? Basically, when you try to scroll down, the height should increase, creating a scroll bar, and when you scroll back up, the extra height decreases, and the scroll bar disappears.

## what I tried

I tried

```
document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    let thing = document.querySelector(".container .child");
    thing.style.height = parseFloat(thing.style.height) + 3 + "px";
});
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: like that? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33596240/how-to-get-work-infinite-scroll-depending-on-div-containers-scroll-position

Answer (score 0):

Notice that thing.style.height is defined in px terms so you can't just add 3 to it (

e.g.

```
40px + 3 + 'px'
```

isn't going to work.

Also, if you could show us your HTML it would help as it's possible the style isn't set right at the beginning anyway.